# I can't install angular-cli latest version (13.0.0) globally in my windows-10 machine

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, node-modules, angular13

My Node Version is: v16.14.2
My NPM Version is: 8.5.0

It always shows that:

npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories

And

'C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules'

[image]

How Can I resolve this issues.

Comment: Please add the error message as text. You can try to delete the directory manually.

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc